# Joint distribution of exponential and uniform random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose we have continuous random variable **X** with exponential distribution with parameter λ and continuous random variable **Y** with uniform distribution on an interval [$a$, **X**], where $a$ is some number and **X** is fixed.

How do we find the joint distribution function of **X** and **Y**?

Is it true that I have to break it up into cases like $x\le a$ and $y\le a$, and consider a product of the distribution functions of **X** and **Y** on the interval as their joint distribution function?

Comment: What happens for $X < a$? Is $Y$ still defined? If $a$ is a negative number, then there is no problem.

Comment: Indeed, this is only well-defined when $a\leqslant0$.

Comment: Indeed, in my task $a=-3$.

Comment: And yes, if $X\lt a$ $\textbf{F(y)}$ will be $0$. My question is what will happen, for example, if $X\ge a$? How should I write joint distribution function in that case?

Comment: Also, if $X\lt a$ $\textbf{F(x)}$ will be $0$ as well, since $\textbf{X}$ is exponential. Consequently, I can conclude that   $\textbf{F(xy)}$ is also $0$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $a < 0$.
The marginal distributions of ${\bf X}$ is:

$$f_{\bf X}(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}.$$

The conditional distribution of ${\bf Y}$ knowing ${\bf X}$ is:

$$f_{\bf Y|\bf X}(y|x) = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{1}{x-a} & \text{for}~y \in [a, x]\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$

Notice that, the conditional distribution of ${\bf Y}$ knowing ${\bf X}$ [is defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Conditional_continuous_distributions):

$$f_{\bf{Y}|\bf{X}}(y|x)  = \frac{f_{\bf{X},\bf{Y}}(x,y)}{f_{\bf{X}}(x)}.$$

Therefore:

\begin{align}
f_{\bf{X},\bf{Y}}(x,y) & = f_{\bf{Y}|\bf{X}}(y|x)f_{\bf{X}}(x)\\
& = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda x}}{x-a} & \text{for}~y \in [a, x]\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}& 
\end{align}